# Programs layout direction

Tags: windows-7

Lately I've encountered a few programs that for some strange reason display their text-direction from right to left.

Screenshots:

[image: QtAssist]
[image: CodeBlocks]

As you can see the menus, and basically any common control is displayed right-to-left.
How could I fix this? I've been through the Control Panel's: Region and Language, but I couldn't find a solution. Google searches didn't show anything valuable either.

Comment: What language is the version of Windows you're using?

Comment: @MichaelHampton English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While desperately trying to find a solution, I messed around with anything I could find.

I went to Control Panel: Region and Language, and changed the Format to English (United States). I don't understand what this has to do with anything, since this is just the representation of numbers, currency, dates etc. but it worked.

I hope it will change in future releases of Windows to make our lives much easier.

Comment: What format was it in before you had it set to `English (United States)`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Hebrew. Although I've found that setting it to either Hebrew, Arabic, or Farsi will cause this. (basically all the RTL languages)

Comment: Combine what you just said and replace "The direction the text is rendered in" instead of "etc." in your answer and you will have figured out exactly why this happened.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Format is time, date and currency settings, and should have nothing to do with display of programs.
nevertheless, do you think that computers with RTL languages installed should see English programs as shown in the screenshots?

Comment: That is the fault of the program designer setting `RightToLeft` to yes ([the default is no](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S3X1y.png)) and not having the RTL language translation available in their resource files.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I figure the cause is that the program inherits this property from the system in those programs, because I've seen this happen quite a lot, and it's absurd that the developer meant to provide a translation in few of those particular cases. so yes, the fault is with the designer, but the system shares the "blame" as-well IMO.

Comment: It is more likely the program supports multiple languages but you don't have that language's translation downloaded so to returned to the default (English) but it left the formatting on. I would recommend reporting it as a bug to the developer. (FYI Code::Blocks only has [59 of the 2173 strings translated](https://translations.launchpad.net/codeblocks/trunk/+pots/codeblocks/he/+translate?start=0&batch=10&show=translated&field.alternative_language=&field.alternative_language-empty-marker=1&old_show=all) in to Hebrew)